# Why does the image not display?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why does the image not display to the canvas in this example?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
/*
var lockOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

if (lockOrientation("landscape-primary")) {
  screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
} 
*/
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var width = 470;
var height = 310;

var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
       context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="470" height="310" style="border:5px solid #123456;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the script just before the ending tag `</body>`

Comment: Check your browser's console error. You will know why. http://jsfiddle.net/oxokcL3q/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the document to load before trying to select elements in the page.

Try wrapping your code like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // your code goes here
};
```

Comment: Does the code always have to be in the onload or can it be placed outside of that. I read somewhere that if you place it at the end of the html document that it loads first or does the page load last. This is a big thing in the development of some applications. Do you know what Firefox OS prefers.